# Confused about 64-bit registers - ASM

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm, system-calls

I'm currently learning assembly, I'm using Intel syntax on a 64bit ubuntu, using nasm.

So I found two websites that reference the syscalls numbers:

This one for 32 bit registers (eax, ebx, ...): https://syscalls.kernelgrok.com

This one for 64 bits registers (rax, rbx, ...): https://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64

The thing is that my code doesn't work when I'm using the 64 bits syscall numbers, but it works when I replace the 'e' from the 32 bit registers by a 'r', so for instance in sys_write I use rbx to store the fd instead of rdi as  and it works.

I'm quite lost right now.  This code doesn't work:

```
message db 'Hello, World', 10

section .text
global _start
_start: mov rax,4
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, message
        mov rdx, 13
        syscall
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 0
        syscall
```

Comment: If you write 64 bit code, you should use 64 bit system calls.  Note that the arguments go into different registers than with 32 bit system calls.  Please post your code if you want debug help.

Comment: Are you also changing your code from using `int 0x80` to `syscall`?

Comment: We can't use int 0x80 int 64 bit ?

Comment: ```section .data
message db 'Hello, World', 10

section .text
global _start
_start: mov rax,4
        mov rbx, 1
        mov rcx, message
        mov rdx, 13
        int 80h
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 0
        int 80h``` this code works

Comment: Put the code you claim doesn't work into your question with an [edit].  `int 0x80` system calls only ever look at the low 32 bits of registers which is why you shouldn't use them in 64-bit code.  But that means your code would work fine with `mov ecx, message` and so on, *if* it works with `mov rcx, message`.  See [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730).  Were you putting the pointer in `esi` or `rsi` before `int 0x80`?  Of course that doesn't work, the calling convention and call numbers differ, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `strace ./my_program` - you make a bogus `stat` system call, then `write` which succeeds, then fall off the end and segfault.

```
$ strace ./foo 
execve("./foo", ["./foo"], 0x7ffe6b91aa00 /* 51 vars */) = 0
stat(0x1, 0x401000)                     = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
write(0, "Hello, World\n", 13Hello, World
)          = 13
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0xd} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**It's not register names that are your problem, it's call numbers.  You're using 32-bit call numbers but calling the 64-bit `syscall` ABI.**

Call numbers *and* calling convention both differ.

`int 0x80` system calls only ever look at the low 32 bits of registers which is why you shouldn't use them in 64-bit code.

The code you posted in a comment with `mov rcx, message` would work fine with `mov ecx, message` and so on, *if* it works with `mov rcx, message`.  See [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730).

Note that writing a 32-bit register zero-extends into the full 64-bit register so you should always use `mov edi, 1` instead of `mov rdi, 1`.  (Although NASM will do this optimization for you to save code-size; they're so equivalent that some assemblers will silently do it for you.)

Comment: Thank's mate, I got really confused with all the 32/64bit stuff, you really helped me here ! Also I think it's because i'm working on mac AND ubuntu and Mac OS 64 syscall numbers seem to be the same as linux 32

Comment: @Ajvar The system call numbers are different on each system.  For historical reasons, some system call numbers are the same on many systems but you shouldn't rely on that.  The best way to do system calls is to use the libc wrappers as those are portable, allowing your program to be run on multiple systems.

Comment: And for the zero extend thing, shouldn't I use 8 bit registers then ?

Comment: @Ajvar No as writes to 8 bit registers are not automatically zero-extended to the whole 64 bit.  This only happens when you write to a 32 bit register.

Comment: @Ajvar: [Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11177137)  Unfortunately no x86 extension has ever added an opcode for `mov r/m32, sign_extended_imm8` which would save 2 bytes on every mov-immediate to register, or more for negative values to 64-bit regs.  And 3 bytes per instruction with a memory destination.  AMD64 could have, since it freed up several opcodes, but AMD64 was very conservative perhaps because AMD weren't sure it would even catch on :(

Comment: @Ajvar: the base call numbers on MacOS are similar to Linux, but you need to set some hit bits as flags for 64-bit MacOS syscalls.